# How acces GPIO pins of banana pi in qt

Tags: qt, gpio, banana-pi

i want to use GPIO pins of banana pi in Qt. i want to set one pin to high and then one pin to low  based on status of other pin . how to use it? i read from Google search that mmapGpio.h is library for raspberry pi .is it is similar for banana pi?

Answer (score 0):

Here, See this link, best way for banana pi.

```
http://wiki.lemaker.org/BananaPro/Pi:GPIO_library
```

Just as we use `WiringPI` library for Raspberry PI, you can use `WiringBP` library for basic usage. After installing `WiringBP`, you can have library for python too to program you GPIO.

See `WiringBP` similar to `WiringPI`

```
https://github.com/LeMaker/WiringBP
```

A working example, you can find with python using `WiringPi2` in banana here.

```
http://forum.lemaker.org/thread-447-1-1.html
```